# Using PHP and MySQL, need to change columns in a table. Query not preparing.

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to change stuff in tables through PHP. This is that part script. In the first if statement, it calls something went wrong with the query. What is wrong?

```
    if (!($query = $db->prepare('UPDATE Accounts SET firstname=:firstname, lastname=:lastname, age=:age, location=:location WHERE username=:username')) === false) {
        exit('{"result": "something went wrong preparing the query"}');
    }

    if (!$query->execute(array('firstname' => $_POST['firstname'], ':lastname' => $_POST['lastname'], ':age' => $_POST['age'], ':location' => $_POST['location'], ':username' => $_POST['username']))) {
        exit('{"result": "something went wrong executing query"}');
    } else {
        exit('{"result": "changed fields"}');
    }
```

Comment: Did you debug the result array of: `array('firstname' => $_POST['firstname'], ':lastname' => $_POST['lastname'], ':age' => $_POST['age'], ':location' => $_POST['location'], ':username' => $_POST['username'])` ?

Comment: Do you get a error message?

Comment: Something obviously has gone wrong. Add `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened to find out what it is. Plus, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` which won't hurt.

Comment: @Fred-ii- okay. i did    $secondQuery = 'UPDATE Accounts SET firstname=' . $_POST['firstname'] . ', lastname=' . $_POST['lastname'] . ', age=' . $_POST['age'] . ', location=' . $_POST['location'] . 'WHERE username=' . $_POST['username'];
   if (!mysql_query($secondQuery, $db)) {
    exit('{"result": "something went wrong executing query"}');
   } else {
    exit('{"result": "changed fields"}');
   }

Comment: @Fred-ii- then i get <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given in <b>/var/www/photoshare.benrosen.org/public_html/api/ChangeAccountInfo.php</b> on line <b>21</b><br /> as an error.

Comment: This tells me that you're mixing MySQL APIs using PDO and `mysql_query()` those do **not** mix together. Either you use all PDO or all `mysql_` functions. But, am sure you want to stick with PDO. You cannot have any `mysql_` functions mixed with PDO; it's one or the other. ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii-Can you write replacement code for my original code in the post pls.

Comment: You will need to post your full code in your question. Plus, read up on [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements)

Comment: PDO normally throws exceptions which usually are more informative than "something went wrong preparing the query". I would recommend changing error handling to exceptions, at least for the debugging phase to see what exactly mysql is complaining about. Check PDO error handling for details on how to do that, and then post received exception details.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use standard prepared statements (eg like [seen here](https://www.inanimatt.com/php-prepared-statements.html)):

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE title = :title';
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':title', $myTitle);
$stmt->execute();
```

This way you will get a better idea where things go wrong...

Answer (score 0):

This looks like PDO.

Example 2 on [PDO Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) states that you need to

```
$sth->execute(array(':calories' => $calories, ':colour' => $colour));
```

In your code, you're missing ":" in "firstname" inside your array.

Comment: No, you did the same thing that a deleted answer included, which you are not able to see; only `10k+` members can. This is **not** the problem. Go over the comments under OP's question to find out the real reason. The placeholder being in `SET firstname=:firstname` etc. is the most important thing, and not in the array.

Comment: Agreed, now I saw that it fails on the first statement. However it will likely fail due to placeholder missing ":" once the first issue is found.

Comment: [`Read this particular comment by the OP`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347564/using-php-and-mysql-need-to-change-columns-in-a-table-query-not-preparing#comment41356945_26347564) - **that** is the reason why. OP is mixing MySQL APIs and hasn't posted full code, only in the comments section, which is never reliable and is hard to read also.

Comment: This message tells me that he put a PDO handle into mysql_query function instead of a resource. Which probably means that his original code was working with PDO, and in that case $query = $db->prepare('...'); Should work provided the underlying mysql table has a compatible schema. Again, without a clear error, it is a lot of guessing

Comment: Indeed, a lot of guessing, which is why I did not put in an answer till I see all of the components.